# mysql join two tabes two columns not equal

Tags: mysql, join

For example  table-A (id,number)
table-B(id,number)

now I want to delete Table-B records if id,number combination does not exist in table-A.
Can you any one help me on this?
sample data:

**table-A**

```
11,1001

12,1231

13,3451
```

**table-B**

```
11,3451

12,1231

54,1001
```

so i need to delete 11,3451; 54,1001 records from table-B

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this to get the IDs that need to be deleted:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table-B b
LEFT JOIN Table-A a on b.id = a.id AND b.number = a.number
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

Comment: join not working ,each table contains 30 lakhs records.